# What equations do I need to find the requested parameters?

Tags: control

> Consider a filter of the form $$ _{posic}() = \alpha_1+\alpha_2e^{-sh}.$$
> Find the parameters \$\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in \mathbb R\$, and \$h > 0\$ such that
>
> 1. \$P_{\theta\phi}_{posic}\$ is an FIR (finite impulse response)  system
> 2. the static gain \$_{posic} = 1\$,
> 3. \$h\$ is a smallest possible delay guaranteeing all that
>    in symbolic form in terms of the parameters of the system,
>
> given \$ P_{\theta\phi} = -\frac{mlrs^2}{(J_b+ml^2)s^2 + \zeta s + mlg}\$,
> where \$ m,l,r,J_b \$   are known constants.

I've tried computing the poles and then using \$ Res(G(s),s_i) = 0 \$ to satisfy 1. (since my poles are simple and this should guarantee FIR)  and a third equation from 2. but the system of equations I get doesn't have a nontrivial solution.

How do I approach finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Impulse response of \$P(s)\$ contains the complex conjugated pole pair $$p_1 = j\cdot\omega - \rho$$
$$p_2 = -j\cdot\omega - \rho$$
and a weighted unshifted dirac impulse. Hence the impulse response looks like
$$p(t) = A\cdot\delta(t) + B\cdot\cos(\omega t) e^{-\rho t}\Theta(t) \\ + C\cdot\sin{(\omega t)}e^{-\rho t}\Theta(t)$$ where \$\Theta(t)\$ denotes the step function. The dirac impulse (shifted or weighted) will always be of "finite length". The only part we need to worry about are the oscillating and decaying parts of infinite duration. Next, notice what happens when we shift the exponential signals by half a period :
Cos-part:
$$ s_1(t - T/2) = B\cdot\cos(\omega (t - \frac{\pi}{\omega})) e^{-\rho (t - T/2) } \\ \cdot\Theta(t - T/2)= -\cos{(\omega t}) e^{-\rho t }e^{\rho T/2 } \Theta(t - T/2)\\ = -s_1(t)\cdot e^{\rho T/2 } \Theta(t -T/2)$$
Sin-part:
$$ s_2(t - T/2) = B\cdot\sin(\omega (t - \frac{\pi}{\omega})) e^{-\rho (t - T/2) } \\ \cdot\Theta(t - T/2)= -\sin{(\omega t}) e^{-\rho t }e^{\rho T/2 } \Theta(t - T/2)\\ = -s_2(t)\cdot e^{\rho T/2 } \Theta(t -T/2)$$
where we made use of the fact that $$\Theta(t)\cdot\Theta(t-T/2) =\Theta(t-T/2).$$ This implies that shifting the exponential signals by half a period will generate the negated original signal weighted by a constant exponential factor \$e^{\rho T/2 }\$. One can use this fact to cancel out said signal components by adding the original signal with the appropriatly amplyfied shifted one as is done with the Filter \$F(s)\$. Choose \$a_2 = a_1\cdot e^{-\rho T/2 }\$ , \$a_1\$ arbitrary and \$h = T/2\$. Applying this filter yields the following impulse response:
$$a_1\cdot(\delta(t) + e^{-\rho T/2 }\cdot\delta(t-T/2))*p(t) \\
= a_1\cdot(\delta(t) + e^{-\rho T/2 }\cdot\delta(t-T/2))*(A\cdot\delta(t)) + a_1\cdot(\delta(t) + e^{-\rho T/2 }\cdot\delta(t-T/2))*(s_1(t) + s_2(t)) \\
= a_1\cdot A\cdot(\delta(t) + e^{-\rho T/2 }\cdot\delta(t-T/2)) + a_1\cdot(s_1(t) -s_1(t)\cdot\Theta(t-T/2))
+ a_1\cdot(s_2(t) -s_2(t)\cdot\Theta(t-T/2)).$$
From here on it should be obvious that the terms
$$a_1\cdot(s_k(t) -s_k(t)\cdot\Theta(t-T/2))$$ will be equal to \$0\$ for \$t\$ greater than \$T/2\$. This shows that the final imulse response of the filtered system is of finite length \$T/2\$ where the shift by only a half period makes use of the resulting negation (and is therefore the smallest shift which forces a cancellation of the exponential signals). The static gain of the cascaded systems can be choosen freely via the free Gain-parameter \$a_1\$ of the filter \$F(s)\$.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand the part where you shifted the eponential signal. Are there any skipped steps there? why is only the cos() part shifted? Also can you show how did you apply the filter? I mean where did \$ a_2 \$ go?

Comment: I modified the answer by including more intermediate steps which should answer your questions.